# Action Sheet warning?

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview, delegates, uiactionsheet

I have added an action sheet in my app. My application is tab bar based app. 
I have added this in this way

```
actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil
                              delegate:self
                              cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                              destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                              otherButtonTitles:@"Take photo",@"Use existing photo",nil]; 
actionSheet.actionSheetStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
[actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.view];
```

But it shows warning: [image]

How can I remove it. As the same time I am in the tab in which I want to display the action sheet.

Comment: If you want to show it from the tab bar, then you have to pass the tab bar reference and not UIView (self.view). Hence it is saying incompatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are use tabbar controller then use like this

```
[actionSheet showFromTabBar:(UITabBar *)[appDelegate.tabBarController view]];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
[actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
```

Try this ,it might help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in the tab, shouldn't it be `[actionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];`?

Comment: Can you tell me where you are calling this code from? The view controller? If so, are you using the tab bar controller or a view controller with a `UITabBar` object?

Comment: Using tabbar controller in app delegate class. And in tabbar 1 using this code.

Comment: Updated answer. By TabBar 1, I assume you mean the view controller at tab bar 1.